# Finding the position of UI elements (textbox, buttons etc)

Tags: gui

I would like to ask you if there is any API in Ubuntu distribution, with which I could get some information about every window's element (ex. the position of a textbox/button). In Windows there is the [Automation Element](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/obtaining-ui-automation-elements) class.